# loading data from file to excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have this job I need to do in VBA, and if I open the IDE and run the code from there all behaves as expected, loads the data from txt file to a new temp workbook, copy and paste to my worksheet, close the temp workbook.

But when running using a shortcut, i.e. Ctr+Sft+L, it loads the data to the temp workbook, activates it and stops execution there... Doesn't paste the data back to the worksheet. How can I fix this?

Here's the code:

```
Sub Load_Text() 
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet 
    InsertWorkSheet ("Data") 

    Set wsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data") 

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\w059\Desktop\20121107_Report.txt", _ 
    Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _ 
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, _ 
    Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), _ 
    Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True 
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy wsSheet.Range("A1") 
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True 
End Sub 
Public Sub InsertWorkSheet(name As String) 
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set wsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(name) 

    If wsSheet Is Nothing Then 
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).name = name 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Am I missing the point?  I can't see any PASTE command in your macro - just a copy.  Incidentally, when you insert a worksheet in a workbook it automatically becomes the current one, so you could use ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add followed by ActiveSheet.Name = Name.  On another point, I'd avoid using reserved words like NAME for the names of arguments and variables, as this can lead to strange errors occurring (it would be the first thing I'd change in this macro).

Comment: +1 @AndyBrown welcome to StackOverFlow :) good to see you here. How is the [Wise Owl blog going?](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/author/AndyBrown.htm)?

Comment: @AndyBrown there is an implicit Destination:=wsSheet.Range("A1") in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy wsSheet.Range("A1")

Comment: kooska - so there is.  Apologies for that.
bonCodigo - time-consumingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting a wrong reference to the ActiveWorkbook. This corrected it:

Replaced

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy wsSheet.Range("A1") 
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
```

With

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
wb.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy wsSheet.Range("A1")
wb.Close True
```